# Text box in side by side images

Tags: tables, boxes

I have multiple images in beamer slide. I want to put a text box at extreme right side of images ( I have 3 columns and 4th column I want as a text). How can I do that? Or may a table at the extreme right side in which I could write small text for each row?[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
    \quad
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
    \quad
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}  
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
    \quad
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
    \quad
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
 \quad
 \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
\quad
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}  
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
\quad
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
\quad
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}
    \caption{I want to add a column to the right hand side or a text box so that I could explain the images of each row. }  
\end{figure} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you show the code you want to modify?

Comment: @Ignasi.Please find the code . I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{cccp{4cm}} % say
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
your text \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
your text \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
your text \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
   \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{A.PNG}&
your text 
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code works but I see 2 problems. 1) text is not aligned with images. It's slightly below. 2) \caption no longer works now. Can you please advise me something?

Comment: @LatexUser 1) Without explicit information I can only suggest using parameters, moving pictures OR text top or bottom. 2) You can put the whole table into one `figure`. It is even better, because your previous caption, used for one of figures, is for the whole group of them, if I properly understand your wishes. You can also use a `caption`-like package, which does not produce floats, but only captions.